# How to create all interaction variables between 2 groups of features with sklearn transformers?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Say I have a DataFrame `df` with 5 columns, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`.

What's the most natural way, using scikit-learn transformers, to create the 6 interactions between one feature amongst `['a', 'b', 'c']` and one of `['d', 'e']` (namely `df['a'] * df['d']`, `df['a] * df['e']`, `df['b'] * df['d']`, etc.) ?

I'd like to avoid using a FunctionTransformer as I need to pickle a Pipeline containing this step.